# 2013 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, election, moderators

The 2013 Community Moderator Election is now <s>underway!</s> completed!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on Meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

We also have an [election chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7568/programmers-2013-moderator-elections), for open discussion.

Comment: why isn't this announcement tagged [meta-tag:featured]?

Comment: @gnat there is already the even listed in a different color, do we really need the meta notification in the bulletin as well

Comment: @Ryathal I do not insist on tagging, just want to understand why it isn't

Comment: @gnat The [featured] tag makes the post stick to the community bulletin, which isn't really necessary for this post as the election notification was on the bulletin anyway.

Comment: I see - that makes good sense - thanks @YannisRizos